# Why is an isomorphism between (total) algebras required to have an inverse which is a homomorphism?

Tags: universal-algebra

Let us consider homomorphisms between partial algebras as defined in

https://planetmath.org/homomorphismbetweenpartialalgebras

There, an isomorphism from $A$ to $B$ is a

1. bijective homomorphism from $A$ to $B$
2. such that its inverse is a homomorphism, too.

I can see that for partial algebras the second condition is necessary.  Is the second condition also necessary if $A$ is a *total* algebra, or can this condition be dropped? I.e., is condition 2 implied by condition 1 when $A$ is total?

Comment: The second condition is always necessary, but for some structures it is implied by the first. Is your question if 2 is implied by 1?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the second condition is implied by the first when $A$ is total. Indeed, if $f$ is a bijective (or even just surjective) homomorphism $A\to B$ and $A$ is total, then $B$ is also total, since for all function symbol $\varphi$ of arity $n$ and all $b_1,\cdots,b_n\in B$ we can find $a_1,\cdots,a_n\in A$ such that $f(a_i)=b_i$, and then
$$\varphi(b_1,\cdots, b_n)=\varphi(f(a_1),\cdots,f(a_n))$$
is defined and equal to $f(\varphi(a_1,\cdots,a_n))$.

In particular $f$ is a bijective homomorphism between algebras, and thus its inverse is also an homomorphism by the usual argument.